# Will doing fork multiple times affect performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, amazon-ec2

I need to read log files (.CSV) using fastercsv and save the contents of it in a db (each cell value is a record). The thing is there are around 20-25 log files which has to be read daily and those log files are really large (each CSV file is more then 7Mb). I had forked the reading process so that user need not have to wait a long time but still reading 20-25 files of that size is taking time (more then 2hrs). Now I want to fork reading of each file i.e there will be around 20-25 child process getting created, my question is can I do that? If yes will it affect the performance and is fastercsv able to handle this?
ex:

```
for report in @reports
  pid = fork {
   .
   .
   .
   }
  Process.dispatch(pid)
end
```

PS:I'm using rails 3.0.7 and Its going to happen in server which is running in amazon's large instance(7.5 GB of memory, 4 EC2 Compute Units (2 virtual cores with 2 EC2 Compute Units each), 850 GB of local instance storage, 64-bit platform)

Answer (score 1):

If the storage is all local (and I'm not sure you can *really* say that if you're in the cloud), then forking isn't likely to provide a speedup because the slowest part of the operation is going to be disc I/O (unless you're doing serious computation on your data). Hitting the disc via several processes isn't going to speed that up at once, though I suppose if the disc had a big cache it might help a bit.

Also, 7MB of CSV data isn't really that much - you might get a better speedup if you found a quicker way to insert the data. Some databases provide a bulk load function, where you can load in formatted data directly, or you could turn each row into an INSERT and file that straight into the database. I don't know how you're doing it at the moment so these are just guesses.

Of course, having said all that, the only way to be sure is to try it!

Comment: Exactly.  Build a simple script that spawns 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on children and benchmark the average throughput.  If you've got 16 SSDs and a caching RAID controller you're gonna be able to handle a LOT more parallel imports than on a single 5400RPM SATA drive with no caching RAID controller.

Comment: My guess is that if it's real slow the OP is doing single inserts in individual transactions.

Comment: Good call - the popular databases let you insert multiple rows in statement, which would speed things up. Or, prepared statements would help too.